# ERROR: shinyjs: Error parsing the JavaScript code provided

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to run the shiny dashboard through batch file in windows. Here is my `run.r` file looks like

```
require(shiny)
require(shinyjs)
folder_address = 'E://Dash'
runApp(folder_address, launch.browser=TRUE)
```

Here is my `batch file` looks like

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\R.exe" -e "shiny::runApp('E:/Dash', launch.browser=TRUE)"
```

But,whenever I run the batch file it opens up the browser and throws this error

```
ERROR: shinyjs: Error parsing the JavaScript code provided.
```

Answer (score 0):

To run a shiny app located in `E:\Dash` from a batch file in windows:

1. You can get the library folder running this function in R:

   ```
   .libPaths()
   "C:/Users/me/Documents/R/R-3.3.1/library"
   ```
2. Your run.R should be:

   ```
   require(shiny)
   folder_address = 'E:/Dash'
   runApp(folder_address, launch.browser=TRUE)
   ```
3. Your run.BAT should be:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\Rscript.exe" E:/Dash/run.R R_LIBS="C:/Users/me/Documents/R/R-3.3.1/library"
   ```

Comment: Did not understand the path `R_LIBS`